# The argument type 'double' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'VisualDensity?'

Tags: flutter

IconButton(//... visualDensity: VisualDensity.minimumDensity,), // The argument type 'double' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'VisualDensity?'. Why can't I assign?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the next time you run into an error like this, what it is basically telling you is that you're trying to pass the wrong data to the parameter.

For your case this is what you should do

```
IconButton(onPressed: (){}, icon: Icon(Icons.enhance_photo_translate), visualDensity: VisualDensity(horizontal: 4.0, vertical: 4.0),)
```

Pass a visual density object and not a double primitive type.

Answer (score 0):

The type of visualDensity is nullable. Try using `VisualDensity.minimumDensity!`

I also suggest adding a null check. `VisualDensity.minimumDensity == null ? 0.0 : VisualDensity.minimumDensity!`

Comment: The error already states that you can't pass in a double so checking null won't solve it,
VisualDensity.minimumDensity! is returning a double and this is only saying that it should not be null but the problem is that you are still passing a double which it will not take.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit confusing and unintuitive.

### Explanation

While for example VisualDensity.standard, VisualDensity.comfortable and  VisualDensity.compact  are defined as VisualDensity object, VisualDensity.minimumDensity and VisualDensity.maximumDensity are defined as double.

Have a look into the implementation of VisualDensity:

```
static const VisualDensity standard = VisualDensity();
static const VisualDensity comfortable = VisualDensity(horizontal: -1.0, vertical: -1.0);
static const VisualDensity compact = VisualDensity(horizontal: -2.0, vertical: -2.0);

/// The minimum allowed density.
static const double minimumDensity = -4.0;
/// The maximum allowed density.
static const double maximumDensity = 4.0;
```

### Solution

So if you want VisualDensity with minimumDensity, you can do the following:

```
visualDensity: const VisualDensity(
   horizontal: VisualDensity.minimumDensity,
   vertical: VisualDensity.minimumDensity,
),
```